# ‘_curses.error: curses function returned NULL’ with windows-curses

Tags: python

Was trying to copy a project which includes working with Python's Curses Module.
Since it is originally for MacOS and Linux, so downloaded it on Windows via the following command

```
pip install windows-curses
```

Initial Code goes as follows...

```
import curses
curses.initscr()
win = curses.newwin(50, 50, 0, 0)
```

Facing following problem after running in VSCode Terminal...

```
   win = curses.newwin(50, 50, 0, 0)
_curses.error: curses function returned NULL
```

Tried running through the docs, couldn't fix the problem.

Anyone please tell why is it going wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: It's unlikely that you're going to get a curses application to run from inside an IDE - the IDE probably doesn't implement the terminal control features that curses is based on.  Try running your program directly from a Windows command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

When the terminal is too small
try to test it in full screen mode (**terminal**)